# Best practices how to filter logs in project

Tags: python, logging, buildout

I'm using python and buildout in my project.

From time to time I have logs from different packages via python logging package.

Logs have information about IP address or even worse user passwords.

I know and using filters to filter logs.

My question is the way how to add this filters or package that allow to organize all filters via buildout configuration?

Comment: I think the better answer to this is to fix the code so it doesn't log sensitive information to begin with. Otherwise, your filter rule set just might miss that one odd corner case that doesn't happen very frequently, and information will still leak.

Comment: I partly agree with you but in my case, the lib that is logging doesn't know about which data has to be hidden, it only logs request that contains an error with all data that needs to reproduce it like request data. In my case if it happens on login form it logs user login name and password from request, I know that all requests from login form should be hidden but lib doesn't.